# mbed ethernet interface not working

Tags: c, mbed

I have a NXP FRDM-K64F board and I want to set the ethernet example but I cannot get it working. This is how my code looks like after setting the static IP address.

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "main-hw.h"
#include "EthernetInterface.h"

// Network interface
EthernetInterface net;


int main(void)
{
    // Bring up the ethernet interface
    printf("Ethernet socket example\r\n");

    int ret;
    ret = net.set_network("192.168.15.177","255.255.255.0","192.168.15.1");
    printf("Set Net: %d\r\n",ret);

    char macadd[6];
    mbed_mac_address(macadd);
    printf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x \r\n", macadd[0], macadd[1], macadd[2], macadd[3], macadd[4], macadd[5]); 

    const char *mac = net.get_mac_address();
    printf("MAC address is: %s\r\n", mac ? mac : "No MAC");

    const char *ip = net.get_ip_address();
    printf("IP address is: %s\r\n", ip ? ip : "No IP");

    ret = net.connect();
    printf("Connect: %d\n",ret);

    // Show the network address
   // const char *ip = net.get_ip_address();
   // printf("IP address is: %s\n", ip ? ip : "No IP");

    // Open a socket on the network interface, and create a TCP connection to mbed.org
    TCPSocket socket;
    socket.open(&net);
    socket.connect("developer.mbed.org", 80);

    // Send a simple http request
    char sbuffer[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: developer.mbed.org\r\n\r\n";
    int scount = socket.send(sbuffer, sizeof sbuffer);
    printf("sent %d [%.*s]\n", scount, strstr(sbuffer, "\r\n")-sbuffer, sbuffer);

    // Recieve a simple http response and print out the response line
    char rbuffer[64];
    int rcount = socket.recv(rbuffer, sizeof rbuffer);
    printf("recv %d [%.*s]\n", rcount, strstr(rbuffer, "\r\n")-rbuffer, rbuffer);

    // Close the socket to return its memory and bring down the network interface
    socket.close();

    // Bring down the ethernet interface
    net.disconnect();
    printf("Done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

What I see is that I only get the macAddress with the mbed_mac_address command. With net.get_mac_address and net.get_ip_address I only get NULL values.

The process get to the net.connect and I see no more results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know this at all (and `net.` looks more C++ than C) but can you step into the `EthernetInterface` constructor or `net.set_network()`? I wouldn't expect the class to have the MAC address unless either of those initialised it. Hopefully you have the EthernetInterface source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mbed OS 5.3.4 this works fine for me on a K64F:

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "EthernetInterface.h"

// Network interface
EthernetInterface net;

// Socket demo
int main() {
    // Set static IP
    net.set_network("192.168.1.99", "255.255.255.0", "192.168.1.1");

    // Bring up the ethernet interface
    printf("Ethernet socket example\n");
    net.connect();

    // Show the network address
    const char *ip = net.get_ip_address();
    printf("IP address is: %s\n", ip ? ip : "No IP");

    printf("MAC address is: %s\n", net.get_mac_address());

    // Open a socket on the network interface, and create a TCP connection to mbed.org
    TCPSocket socket;
    socket.open(&net);
    socket.connect("developer.mbed.org", 80);

    // Send a simple http request
    char sbuffer[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: developer.mbed.org\r\n\r\n";
    int scount = socket.send(sbuffer, sizeof sbuffer);
    printf("sent %d [%.*s]\n", scount, strstr(sbuffer, "\r\n")-sbuffer, sbuffer);

    // Recieve a simple http response and print out the response line
    char rbuffer[64];
    int rcount = socket.recv(rbuffer, sizeof rbuffer);
    printf("recv %d [%.*s]\n", rcount, strstr(rbuffer, "\r\n")-rbuffer, rbuffer);

    // Close the socket to return its memory and bring down the network interface
    socket.close();

    // Bring down the ethernet interface
    net.disconnect();
    printf("Done\n");
}
```

### Updating mbed OS

If you still have the mbed library (not mbed-os) in the online compiler, right click on 'mbed', and click 'Remove'. Then click on 'Add library' > 'From URL' and enter https://github.com/armmbed/mbed-os.

If you have mbed-os, right click on the library and select 'Upgrade'.

From mbed CLI:

```
$ mbed remove mbed
$ mbed add mbed-os
```

Or when you already have mbed-os:

```
$ cd mbed-os
$ git pull
$ git checkout latest
```

Comment: It stops in the same point, on the net.connect();. The code is so simple I don't really know what to change or search for.

Comment: What revision of mbed OS are you on? I've tested this on my home network and it works fine...

Comment: On friday I downloaded the last version present on the repository. I am not able to find how to obtain the revision number, but I understand that I am up to date.

Comment: Are you building locally? If so, use a terminal to go into the mbed-os directory and run `git rev-parse HEAD`. If you're building in the online compiler, click on the library and click on the 'Revisions' button.

Comment: I am building locally (I am clasic one, not happy with online interface :) ). This is the result: 269f58d75b752a4e67a6a2d8c5c698635ffd6752. It is 5.3.4, as I understand.

Comment: Yes, that seems right... I'm on the same revision. If you use the same ethernet cable and plug it in a computer, do you manage to get an internet connection?

Comment: I think i have a network problem. Until I can check it I think that it was the cause of the malfunctioning.